# SpreadJS set cursor at end in keyup event

Tags: javascript, spreadsheet, spreadjs

I am using spreadjs to show spreadsheet in my project.
There is a bug which I need to fix.
1. set the cell text alignment to center/right.
2. Enter some text and then delete it using backspace. 
3. After the backspace is finished(all the text is deleted) then yo try to write "Test" in cell.
Following will be displayed
"estT"

That is why I think if I try to set cursor at end in each keyup event, this bug will be resolved.

Comment: can you please let us know which version of SpreadJS you are using?   I tried what you described and did not see the same behavior.    you can reach out to our support team and share a small video of your experience.

Comment: I have tried it in  12.0.3 and 12.2.5. I forgot to mention that for this scenario we need to set cell text alignment to center/right